# How to rebase onto branch that has overwritten history?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

Say I have branch `1` with commit `A`.

`1: A`

From 1, I create another branch, `2`.

`2: A`

On `2`, I add a commit.

`2: A->B`

Then on `1`, I make some changes and `git commit --amend`, overwriting `A`.

`1: C`

On `2`, I want these new changes on `1` and want to just apply my changes from `B` onto `C`. However, from what I understand, git will see that branch `2` has new commits `A` and `B`, and try to apply both of these commits on top of `C`. So when I'm done rebasing, `2` will look like

`2: C->A->B`

When what I really want is `C->B`.

What would be the proper way to handle this situation? The way I've been dealing with this so far is by creating a new branch off of `1`, and then cherry-picking over commit `B` from `2`. But that seems a bit hacky, and not so trivial to do when `2` has more than just one new commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's lay this out more conventionally and see what's going on.

If A is the first commit things get complicated, so I'll add an ancestor Z.

> Say I have branch 1 with commit A.

```
Z - A [1]
```

> From 1, I create another branch, 2.

```
Z - A [1][2]
```

> On 2, I add a commit.

```
Z - A [1]
     \
      B [2]
```

> Then on 1, I make some changes and git commit --amend, overwriting A.

Here's where things go wonky.

```
  C [1]
 /
Z - A
     \
      B [2]
```

Git never "overwrites" a commit. It can't. The commit ID is a checksum of the commit contents and all its ancestry. What `commit --amend` (and also `rebase`) does is creates new commits and pretends it was that way all along.

But the old commit still sticks around. And if anything has it as an ancestor, like branch 2 here, it will be visible.

> On 2, I want these new changes on 1 and want to just apply my changes from B onto C. However, from what I understand, git will see that branch 2 has new commits A and B, and try to apply both of these commits on top of C. So when I'm done rebasing, 2 will look like 2: C->A->B when what I really want is C->B.

The problem here is because of the `commit --amend` branch 1 and branch 2 no longer have A as a common ancestor. It's now Z. If you try to rebase 2 onto 1 it will put both A and B on top of C.

```
    A1 - B1 [2]
   /
  C [1]
 /
Z - A
     \
      B
```

While that might work, it also might result in a messy conflict. You'll have to use a more precise rebase command to let Git know what you really want. Since C is really a reworked A, what you really want is everything on 2 *after* A.

```
git rebase --onto 1 A..2
```

And the result will be what you want.

```
    B1 [2]
   /
  C [1]
 /
Z - A
     \
      B
```

(A and B won't be visible, and they will be eventually garbage collected.)

---

If you think this is complex and fraught with peril, it is!

This is why it's best to *not* rebase or amend your "stable" branch, usually `master`. Instead, just use a normal commit, or a feature branch for a larger change. Then the normal procedure to update branches applies.